# Windows registry files shadow copy

Tags: windows, file, search, registry

I need to find all windows registry files on disk including backup registry data from windows shadow copy. The problem is I don't know where those files are located.

In internet I found this command
`vssadmin list shadowstorage`
but it returns me this

`For volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{ba406d28-f092-11dc-b3d7-806e6f6e6963}\`

`Shadow Copy Storage volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{ba406d28-f092-11dc-b3d7-806e6f6e6963}\`

What is this? Where those files are really located? How can I access them? If I scan harddrive for binary files with "regf" magic number in the beginning would it be enough to find all registry data?

**ADDED**

I created shortcut on one backup folder from folder properties (Previous Versions)
Here is what shortcut is pointing to

`\\localhost\C$\@GMT-2012.04.12-00.13.21\Windows\System32\config`

Looks like it contains backup files, but is it possible to access it as a normal directory? How can I find those directories on hard drive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run `vssadmin list shadows` (**not** shadowstorage)

You will receive list of the shadow copies with the path to each among other information. Path looks like this:

```
\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1
```

Use that path as a replacement to the volume letter like this:

```
 CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\\Windows\\System32\\config\\SYSTEM", GENERIC_READ, 
FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I want to access those files on the other hard disk (not the one where my current windows is running)? Can I see this copies just as normal files during file scan?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the shadow copy is located, vssadmin should list it.

Comment: vssadmin cannot list it in my specific situation. Image that you have a disconnected hard drive with windows installation on it. You connect this hard drive to your computer running any version of windows and you need to find registry backup files for the windows on connected hard drive. vssadmin can list shadow copies of the windows you are running, but not the ones that we really need.